# Is there a way to download objects from Amazon S3 based on certain tags?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to download objects (files) from `Amazon-S3` but the problem that I am facing is keeping track of which objects have been downloaded as I have plenty of objects in each bucket and they increase with each day.

I have been looking for a way so that I can `set/unset` some tag associated with each object. So when I have to download I can look for all the objects which have that particular tag not set, download them and then set their tag so they are downloaded again next time. Is there a way to do so? A sample example to do so will be helpful.

I am using `boto` to download the objects through python. The current code that I have basically downloads single object that I have to name.

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection

conn = S3Connection( S3 Credentials )
bucket = conn.get_bucket (Bucket Name)
key = bucket.get_key(Object Name)
key.get_contents_to_filename(Local Object Path to Download)
```

**UPDATED CODE:**
I am trying to copy the file from one directory to another directory within the same bucket using `boto's` `copy()` function. Here is my current code:

```
    conn = S3Connection( S3 Credentials )
    bucket = conn.get_bucket (Bucket Name)
    key = bucket.get_key(Object Name)
    key2= bucket.get_key(/new/dir/in_same_bucket/)
    key.get_contents_to_filename(Local Object Path to Download)
    key.copy(bucket.name, key2.name,metadata=None, preserve_acl=True)
```

When I do this I get error as `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'`. How can I copy the file from one directory to another directory within same bucket using `copy()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach arbitrary metadata to S3 objects when you upload the object so that would allow you to set tags when the files are originally uploaded.  But there are still two problems to overcome:

- Unsetting the tags.  S3 doesn't provide a way to modify an object's metadata after the object is created.  It does, however, provide a way for you to COPY the object back onto itself (all server side) and modify the metadata.  So, its a big clunky but you could unset the tags after you have processed the object.
- Querying for tags.  This is the real problem.  There is no way to get a listing of all objects whose metadata contains (or does not contain) a certain value.  You would have to constantly list all objects in the bucket to find the objects that have your tag.  And, to make matters worse, the tags would not be returned in the bucket listing.  You would have to do a `HEAD` request on every object to retrieve it's tags.

If all of the objects that need to be downloaded can be found based on their `LastModifiedDate` you could potentially use that.  You would still have to list all of the objects but the last modified date is returned in the bucket listing data so no `HEAD` request would be required.

Or, you could use a `prefix` to sort your objects.  You could upload all new objects to the bucket using a name like `new/mynewobject` and then get a listing of all objects that have `prefix=new`.  After you download the object you could then use the COPY operation to "move" the object out of the new folder so you won't process it again.

Or you could use a database like DynamoDB to help you keep track of things.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you elaborate the `LastModifiedDate` approach a little bit probably through an example? Also is there a way we can rename a object like after the object had been downloaded we can add some sort of prefix to the object name to make it appear downloaded?

Comment: I have done some modifications to my code above. I was trying to copy(move) the files from one directory to another within the same bucket but am getting an error which i have mentioned in my post above